# Activity result contracts with Ucrop: cannot get crop result into app

Tags: android, kotlin, ucrop, activityresultcontracts

I have an activity that is supposed to get an image from gallery and preview it before allowing the user to upload it to a database. I am using UCrop as my image cropper with Activity Result Contracts for this. The image cropper activity launches successfully but the app is unable to get the result into my Image View for the preview. I can't really tell where the problem is since I'm relatively new to Android and nothing I've found on similar issues seems to help.

Here's my code.

```
class NewPostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var myUrl ?= null
private var imageUri: Uri ?= null
private var storagePostPicRef: StorageReference ?= null
private lateinit var publishPostButton: ImageView
private lateinit var closePostPageButton: ImageView
private lateinit var newPostImageSelector: ImageView


private val uCropContract = object : ActivityResultContract<List<Uri>, Uri>(){
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: List<Uri>): Intent {
        val inputUri = input[0]
        val outputUri = input[1]

        val uCrop = UCrop.of(inputUri, outputUri)
            .withAspectRatio(2F, 1F)
            .withMaxResultSize(1720, 860)

        return uCrop.getIntent(context)
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Uri {
        return getOutput(intent!!)!!
    }
}

private val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()){ uri ->
    val inputUri = uri.toString().toUri()
    val outputUri = File(filesDir, System.currentTimeMillis().toString()+".jpg").toUri()

    val listUri = listOf<Uri>(inputUri, outputUri)
    cropImage.launch(listUri)
}

private val cropImage = registerForActivityResult(uCropContract){
    val uri = intent.data
    imageUri = uri
    newPostImageSelector.setImageURI(imageUri)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_post)

    storagePostPicRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Post Pictures")
    publishPostButton = findViewById(R.id.publishNewPost)
    closePostPageButton = findViewById(R.id.closeAddPost)
    newPostImageSelector = findViewById(R.id.newPostImage)

    publishPostButton.setOnClickListener{
        uploadImage()
    }
    closePostPageButton.setOnClickListener {
        val closeIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(closeIntent)
        finish()
    }
    newPostImageSelector.setOnClickListener {
        getContent.launch("image/*")
    }

}
```

Can anyone help. Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper use this library for image cropping.

Comment: @VishalVasani I did at first but couldn't get the app to build. The Gradle sync result was 'Failed to resolve: com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+' while with https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper I got the suggestion to use activity-ktx and fragment-ktx from androidx library instead.

Comment: it is working fine. I have just checked.

Comment: @VishalVasani of course it's "working fine"... but onActivityResult is deprecated and that library uses it just like uCrop does. So sometime in the near future it will be very much "not fine."

Comment: The library was moved to another location: com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:1.1.1